# Partition shows up in Ubuntu 18.04, but gparted option to mount it is greyed out

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, mount, gparted, raid

This is in Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS

I have a Dell T610 that I'm setting up as a home lab. It has a PERC H700 controller and I havea 4 port SATA controller as well. I currently have:

```
6x 300GB SAS in RAID 10 - This is my OS drive
2x 6TB SATA in RAID 1 - This is the newly created array for file storage

1TB, 2TB, and 4TB HDD on the SATA controller for various media and whatnot
```

When I created partitions for the HDDs on the SATA controller they all mounted automatically to /media/username/ but for some reason creating the partition on the 6TB RAID 1 array and restarting did nothing and the option to mount it in gparted is greyed out.

How do I mount that drive/partition like the rest of them?

---

1st Edit: I'm trying to fix this myself and so far I opened `Disks` and was able to mount the drive from there, however it did not automount after a reboot even though the `User Session Defaults` in `Mount Options` had that checked. I unselected `User Session Defaults` and left `Mount at system startup` and `Show in user interface` selected and rebooted. This time it was automatically mounted.

However, it is not mounted in `/media/username/` like my other drives.

I imagine this drive is being treated differently because Ubuntu sees it as an internal drive and it sees my PCI-E SATA drives as external drives. I would like to keep all of my mount points in one location under `/media/username/` so it would be great to learn how to do that.

I would also like to know why it wasn't automounted in the first place just so I understand how the system works.

Thanks!

---

2nd Edit:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0   956K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/73
loop1    7:1    0  42.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
loop2    7:2    0     4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/406
loop3    7:3    0  84.7M  1 loop /snap/plexmediaserver/27
loop4    7:4    0  88.5M  1 loop /snap/core/7270
loop5    7:5    0 149.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/67
loop6    7:6    0    89M  1 loop /snap/core/7713
loop7    7:7    0 136.7M  1 loop /snap/code/15
loop8    7:8    0  1008K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/61
loop9    7:9    0  54.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1144
loop10   7:10   0   4.2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/501
loop11   7:11   0  14.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/317
loop12   7:12   0  54.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1066
loop13   7:13   0   8.4M  1 loop /snap/canonical-livepatch/81
loop14   7:14   0 149.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/71
loop15   7:15   0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100
loop16   7:16   0  14.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/296
sda      8:0    0 836.6G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 836.6G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0   5.5T  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0   5.5T  0 part /mnt/28B1B12845FEFB99
sdc      8:32   1 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   1 931.5G  0 part /media/mcp/Storage
sdd      8:48   1   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sdd1   8:49   1   1.8T  0 part /media/mcp/TV
sde      8:64   1   3.7T  0 disk 
└─sde1   8:65   1   3.7T  0 part /media/mcp/Movies
Model: DELL PERC H700 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 898GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  898GB  898GB  primary  ext4         boot


Model: DELL PERC H700 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 6001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name   Flags
 1      1049kB  6001GB  6001GB  ntfs         Vault  msftdata


Model: ATA WDC WD10EZEX-08M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ntfs


Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRX-00D (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2000GB  2000GB  ntfs         TV    msftdata


Model: ATA HGST HMS5C4040AL (scsi)
Disk /dev/sde: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name    Flags
 1      1049kB  4001GB  4001GB  ntfs         Movies  msftdata


Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Please Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1176897/edit ) your post to add the data. What does `lsblk;sudo parted -l;lsusb` show? What filesystems have you created?

Comment: I updated the post with two edits that I think help answer the question. The filesystem is ntfs.